# Ok Google from outside the app

Tags: google-apps, ok-google

After I upgraded my system on my Meizu MX5, I see no option in Google App to turn on Ok Google detection from outside the app (`Settings > Voice > "Ok Google" detection >` and here I have only `From the Google app`).

In [Google support website](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6031948?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) I see that "**For certain devices,** you can also change some settings to turn on "Ok Google" detection outside the Google app".

So what are these "certain devices"? I have Android version 5.1. Why can't I use Ok Google from outside the app although I could use it before updating my system?

**edit:**

I opened an issue here: [OK Google options missing](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/websearch/4m6Tcwyn0kM/U2hM-ap6CAAJ)

Answer (score 1):

"certain devices" = devices that meet the requirements (eg. android version)

Now to your problem. It could have many reasons. I assume it's a bug in the Google App. The Samsung Galaxy S6 had the same [problem](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/xGiV6D4PMS8%5B1-25%5D) after a system update because of battery saving settings. Google fixed that. I suspect that some battery saving related settings changed with the system update and now the google voice is no longer available outside the google app. I recommend you to contact google support to solve this issue.